# using ON DUPLICATE KEY with 2 unique columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 columns `date`(primary) and `user_id`(unique).  I want to check if the row exists if not create it, if so update the row for that day.

for example: if a user updates the database multiple times a day I only want 1 record created per day and that record to update every time the user updates the database.  However if the same user(same user_id) updates the database the next day I want a new record created.

I'm using the following code:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

The problem is it doesn't appear to be checking for both `date` AND `user_id` but only the user_id.  How can I get it to check for both? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a single unique index on the table.  Drop your current indexes and define:

```
create unique index idx_table_user_date on table(user, date)
```

This should give you the behavior that you want -- multiple users and multiple dates in the table, but no users have the same date twice (or dates have the same user twice).